# what is the name of this part

Tags: identification, pins, header

I'm trying to be this part separately but I don't really know its exact name therefore I couldn't find it.

[image]
It's the black separators highlighted in the red rectangle that I'm looking for.

I tried looking for pin separators and pin spacers but that didn't result in anything.

[image]

[image]

Comment: These are called "pin header" Actually they come with the pins attached. I have not seen them being sold without the pins.

Comment: No Im looking or the name of the black separators on their on

Comment: Then buy a pinheader, pull out the pins, there you go

Comment: i know but that wont be practical if i'm going to do that for a 100 of them lol so you think they are not sold separately at all ?

Comment: They're never sold separately. You could try talking to Samtec, but they'll probably want to talk volume.

Comment: Never seen them. Also, I see no use for having them without the pins. Perhaps these are made by flowing plastic around the pins during manufacturing so they always contain the pins.

Comment: They are very useful to adjust shield heights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, these spacers are not sold separately (not as a standard part, anyway). However, you can buy headers just like the one you showed in your first picture with the spacers already added. I know Sullins sells some connectors like this with the option of adding these spacers within the order. It's part of the part number configuration. See the catalog page for the PPPC series (http://sullinscorp.com/catalogs/101_PAGE114-115_.100_FEMALE_HDR.pdf). In the fourth table on the first page you'll see the different options for spacers and tail length. I think this is probably what you're looking for. The top of page 2 shows how to configure the part number.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can buy the pin headers with different lengths of pins and pins staked into the plastic to different depths. Quite customizable.

You can contact header manufacturers and see under what conditions they would sell them with no pins at all. I would guess that for < 1K pieces pulling them out as FM says would be your best and most economical bet, but likely short-lead-time specialist guys like [Samtec](https://www.samtec.com/) as @Ignatio says might be amenable, **at a price**. (Ignore the name 'terminal strip', nobody else calls them that).

[image]

You can buy headers with more than one spacer:

[image]

To pull them out, find a piece of perf board, run the pins through (so the FR4 supports the plastic), and pull them out. If they're too grippy, warm the plastic a bit with a heat gun.

Answer (score 0):

I think they're called pin spacers.

As pointed out by @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, they're not sold separately. Maybe they are, but they might be only available for other manufacturers and not for us peasants.

Comment: Pin headers include the pins. The plastic part alone is not called a "pin header".

Comment: I looked at the wrong photo @derstrom8

Comment: @PandaLion90 understood, no worries =)

Comment: Take an upvote @derstrom8

Comment: Much appreciated @PandaLion98!

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't something like a "EW .100" Flex Stack, Flexible Board Stacker, .330" Tail" [Link](https://www.samtec.com/technical-specifications/default.aspx?SeriesMaster=EW) from Samtec work? Comes with two separators... There are other options available (don't know what you pin pitch is)...